# Como obter a data atual com angularJS com refresh na data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como fazer um refresh apenas em um "ng-binding" e não na pagina, pra obter a data atual via angularJS?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function updateTime() {
                scope.time = new Date();
            }
```

Porém preciso fazer um refresh, pra que fique sincronizado com o rélogio, ou seja: Sempre que atualizar o minuto, no meu html ele também atualize.

```
 <span>{{time|date: 'hh:mm a'}}</span>
```

Vi algo sobre o `$interval`mas até o momento não obtive sucesso, se alguém puder explicar como utilizar o mesmo, ou uma outra forma para obter o mesmo resultado, fico grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `$interval`[¹](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) implementa o `window.setInterval`[²](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval), que executa um bloco de código repetidamente, dentro de um intervalo específico. Implementei o código abaixo tomando como referência o [exemplo implementado usando diretivas](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom).

```js
var app = angular.module('clock', []);

app.controller('ClockController', ['$scope', '$interval', 'dateFilter', function($scope, $interval, dateFilter) {
  $scope.currentTime = dateFilter(new Date(), 'hh:mm');
  
  var updateTime = $interval(function() {
    $scope.currentTime = dateFilter(new Date(), 'hh:mm');
  }, 1000);
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="clock" ng-controller="ClockController">
  {{ currentTime }}
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ótima dica, era isso mesmo que eu queria. Mas qual seria a diferença de usar o $timeout e o $interval você saberia me dizer?

Comment: O `$timeout` atrasa a execução da função, enquanto o `$interval` a executa repetidamente. Ou seja, o primeiro executa a função após o intervalo especificado, enquanto o segundo executa a função a cada intervalo.

Comment: obrigado pela explicação. Consegui resolver o meu problema com o $interval. Um abraço.